# Textjoin column headers across range based on another cell value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've been given a spreadsheet of votes for bills. The first row col headings are post IDs from WordPress, and each cell in the column then has Y or N based on each votes. When I import this back into Wordpress, I'm using it to attach each person to the associated posts of bills they voted yes on. This means I need all the ids together in a single column for each person (i.e., combinedvotes col below).

What I'd like to do is essentially run a foreach across a range (there's around 20 bills)... and say if the cell equals "Y", then take then combine the ids into a single list with a delimiter (i.e. textjoin). In the example below, that would make the combinedvotes end up as:

- Jane - 1234;4678;9214
- John - 4678;9214

| Name | 1234 | 4678 | 9214 | combinedvotes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | Y | Y | Y |  |
| John | N | Y | Y |  |

I've been struggling with how to do this across a range. I'm guessing it's probably more of a VBA thing. For the time being I've needed to create an extra column for each bill, check for Y, and then grab the first row value of that column (example: =IF(B2="Y",$B$1,""))...and then finally textjoin across that whole range. It's very inefficient and is much harder to stay organized since I end up needing all these extra columns.

Edit: I should add that I could of course also just find & replace each column and convert the Y value to the associated ID -- but this sheet is updated frequently and I'm always given it in this format -- so I'd rather accomplish this with a function (if possible) so I can avoid the manual work of going column by column find/replace every time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome! Will the formula `{=$A2&" - "&TEXTJOIN(";";1;IF($B2:$D2="Y";$B$1:$D$1;""))}` work for you? (This is an array formula, enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

Comment: Ah, I don't know why I didn't think to use an if across the range. Thanks! Just some formatting fixes here (I didn't need to combine the name as above, sorry that came across so literal :)):


`=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,IF(N2:AE2="Y",$N$1:$AE$1,""))`

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365, you can use the following formula:

```
=LET(array,--("Y"=B2:D2)*($B$1:$D$1),TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,IF(array>0,array,"")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cell E2: =TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Y",$B2:$D2)),$B$1:$D$1,""))
Cell E3: =TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Y",$B3:$D3)),$B$1:$D$1,""))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).